# BSoD after driver removing

Tags: c++, windows, driver, uninstallation

I wrote my first audio driver using a sample from WDK8.0 - MSVAD.
I have no any problems with its installation and working but have a problem when I try to uninstall the driver via Device Manager:

- If the driver  is not used any app, then I remove it without any problems.
- But if I connect a driver to an app, then OS (Win10 x64) requires to reload PC, after it goes to BSoD with the message - SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED. After power reloading the driver was removed in despite of that message.

Any ideas.

The memory dump is here [enter link description here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51370580/Memory_dump.txt)

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug by WinDbg. MSVAD had a failed code in PnpHandler()

```
        ext->m_pCommon->UninstantiateDevices();
        ext->m_pCommon->Release();
        ext->m_pCommon = NULL;
```

Must be

```
    if (ext->m_pCommon != NULL)
    {
        ext->m_pCommon->UninstantiateDevices();
        ext->m_pCommon->Release();
        ext->m_pCommon = NULL;
    }
```